# VBA code to sum totals grouped by invoice

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and would like to automate a rather manual process in excel 2007.

I have a list of invoice numbers in column A (can be up to about 500 lines long), a list of items and any associated accessories in column B and the invoice value/amounts in column C.

What I would like to do is obtain some vba code to total the amounts by invoice number and display the total for each invoice alongside each first appearing invoice (invoice number in column A) and display the total for each invoice in column D (Total).

Can anyone help me with the vba code to do this please.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing you should use [pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) for.

Comment: use formula- `SumIfs()` should work

Comment: I think you can do all this directly on the worksheet. Could you give a specific example please?

Comment: You may want to see [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have headers in row 1 write this formula to `D2` and copy it down until the last row of your list:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,A2),"")
```

Comment: Thankyou, This worked a treat and I recorded a macro to automate it. I was obviuosly looking at a too complicated solution.

Comment: If you are happy with answer you could accept the answer

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum. Just accepted. Thanks again.